# Find the normal "N" on an ellipses through a point on a cross section

Tags: geometry, ellipse, normals

I'm trying to make a nice deflection effect in a little physics engine I've made. Right now it  deflects nicely off the normal of a polygon edge. But instead of making a polygon with 100 edges to get a smooth effect of a "rounded deflection" I figured I could calculate the deflection normal using an ellipse instead.

So, what I'd really like is a function that takes a point *P* on a line segment and returns the normal *N* on the circumference of an imaginary *ellipse(w,h)*. See the attached picture for some details.

[image: A picture of the problem]

To get a point on the circumference of an ellipse I'm pretty sure it's:

```
x=P.x+Math.sin()*w
y=P.y+Math.cos()*h
```

but how can I get the normal from that?

---

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45eFT/5/) with an attempt to implement the answer by Dr BDO Adams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equation of an ellipse point is

```
x=x_centre+a*cos(t)
y=y_centre+b*sin(t)
```

For each point of ellipse you can find `t` as `atan2( (y-y_centre)/b , (x-x_centre)/a )`

When you know `t` tangent direction can be determined: `dx/dt,dy/dt`:

```
dx=-a*sin(t)
dy=b*cos(t)
```

When you know tangent direction, just rotate it by 90 degrees and you have a normal:

```
nx=b*cos(t)
ny=a*sin(t)
```

And to avoid calculating `t` we can combine it with the first two formulas:

```
nx=(x-x_centre)*b/a
ny=(y-y_centre)*a/b
```

Answer (score 0):

First Use the atan2 function to get the angle of at the normal, and get a vector from that

```
theta = atan2(2y/semiminorradius, x/semimajorradius)
ny = semiminorradius * sin(theta)
nx = semimajorradius * cos(theta)
```

Do you need the normal vector to be normalised? (unit length) if so

```
r = sqrt(tx^2+ty^2)
nny = ny/r
nnx = nx/r
```

As you drawn it the point is actually (ny,nx)

Comment: I've tried to implement this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/45eFT/2/) but the resulting unit vector `~(0.55,0.83)` does not look correct. I'd expect something like `(0,1)` or `(0,-1)`.